# How to detect volume up button click event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there anyway to get event from volume up button click from pc or mobile device using js?

Comment: What volume up button? Hardware button on a desktop machine (probably not)? On a mobile device (maybe, but doubtful)? Or a button on a web page (sure thing)?

Comment: @TedHopp Hardware button on PC/mobile!

Comment: Cool questions, that is what I was searching for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In web browsers you don't have access to the volume buttons.

If you want to use the volume buttons, you have to create native application.

Comment: In a browsers "accesibility mode" you can use volume buttons for interacting with a range input element (slider). But how do you detect that event?

Comment: @olefrank brilliant solution. I ended up using Android's accessibility feature + browser slider.